# RethinkDB admin console shows no active connection (v2.3.5 on Windows 7)

Tags: rethinkdb

I've just downloaded RethinkDB v2.3.5 on Windows 7. I run the executable, open the web admin console (`http://localhost:8080`) but it shows no active server connection (see screenshot).

[image: RethinkDB Admin console]

Curiously, connecting to the RethinkDB server with the Node.js client seems to work. Any idea what may be causing this issue?

Note: A few months ago I had tried a previous version of RethinkDB and didn't have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the Edge browser? There might be an incompatibility in the latest version of RethinkDB. You can either use Internet Explorer, Firefox or Chrome instead.

Edit: Link to the issue tracker: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/5878

Comment: I was using Firefox (latest: 48.0.2) and it doesn't work. But you pointed to the right direction, because I switched to Chrome and it now works. I'll comment this on the issue tracker. Important to know there are browser incompatibilities.